# Add intent to an alarm but not run it immediately

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

My scenario is that I want to run the receiver on a specific time that I set with the AlarmManager.

Here is some relevant code:

```
AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
aManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, myTimeInMillis, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0));
```

I have tried to add the FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY-flag to the intent, and this had the desired effect by not running immediately when I created the intent but the AlarmManager didn't seem to be able to run the receiver when that flag was set.

Is it possible to add an intent that will run a broadcast-receiver to an AlarmManager in Android?

Comment: Have you added a `<receiver>` entry to your manifest for `MyBroadcastReceiver`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is working code. It wakes CPU every 10 minutes until the phone turns off.**

Add to Manifest.xml:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
...
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
...
```

Code:

```
    package YourPackage;
    import android.app.AlarmManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.PowerManager;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {    
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
         {   
             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
             wl.acquire();

             // Put here YOUR code.
             Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

             wl.release();
         }

     public void SetAlarm(Context context)
     {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }

     public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(sender);
     }
 }
```

**Set Alarm from Service:**

```
package YourPackage;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class YourService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();       
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
         alarm.SetAlarm(YourService.this);
     return START_STICKY;
}



    public void onStart(Context context,Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        alarm.SetAlarm(context);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**If you want set alarm repeating at phone boot time:**

Add permission to Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
...
<receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
...
```

And create new class:

```
package YourPackage;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            alarm.SetAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked after some tweaking =)
One question though, why do I need the `wakelock`?

Comment: refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333135/what-is-the-use-of-android-permission-wake-lock/22294934#22294934