# Agora.io Video call stops after some minutes of lock screen in android

Tags: java, android, webrtc, agora.io

I'am using Agora.io video call for my application, it is working fine both audio and video, but when I put the device in sleep mode, after some minutes the application probably goes to sleep mode and I'am disconnected from the call channel until I wake up my device again.

I searched the Agora.io documentation for any issue but without success.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: you can request wake lock permission so device won't go to sleep .

Comment: @ManoharReddy can you explain how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333135/what-is-the-use-of-android-permission-wake-lock

Comment: @ManoharReddy So I can use WakeLock.acquire() when the appliction goes in background and this will make the app continue to work?

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED**

I used a `ForegroundService` that set a  Persistent Notification and I was able to ask the service to keep the Camera and Microphone active

```
<manifest>
...
<service ... android:foregroundServiceType="microphone|camera" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: can you share some code snippet or something how you achieved this. we are not able to continue agora call in background even with foreground service.