# Prevent screen dimming when using Unity as a library

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I have used several thing but could not achieved to stop dimming the screen. I am using Unity as a library on my project.

unity library -> AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <application android:extractNativeLibs="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector"
        android:screenOrientation="userLandscape" android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:exported="true">
```

UnityPlayerActivity.java

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

             getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);


        String cmdLine = updateUnityCommandLineArguments(getIntent().getStringExtra("unity"));
        getIntent().putExtra("unity", cmdLine);

        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this, this);
        setContentView(mUnityPlayer);
        mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
    }
```

I have also tried the command line below on my unity project.

```
Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of android permission Wake Lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333135/what-is-the-use-of-android-permission-wake-lock)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem by using setKeepScreenOn.

```
  mUnityPlayer.setKeepScreenOn(true);
```